# generic abstract class for hierarchical structured

Tags: c#, class, generics, types, abstract

I would like to create an abstract class for hierarchical structured objects.

Here is what I already use, but now I want to make it generic

```
   public class EventBase 
{

    private EventBase _Parent;
    virtual public EventBase Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return _Parent;
        }
        set
        {
            _Parent = value;
        }
    }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    private ICustomList<EventBase> _ChildList = new CustomList<EventBase>();
    virtual public ICustomList<EventBase> ChildList
    {
        get
        {
            return _ChildList;
        }
        set
        {
            _ChildList = value;
        }
    }
}
```

something like this:

```
  public class EventBaseGeneric
{

    private GenericTypeThatIsSetInTheInheritingClass _Parent;
    virtual public GenericTypeThatIsSetInTheInheritingClass Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return _Parent;
        }
        set
        {
            _Parent = value;
        }
    }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    private ICustomList<GenericTypeThatIsSetInTheInheritingClass> _ChildList = new CustomList<GenericTypeThatIsSetInTheInheritingClass>();
    virtual public ICustomList<GenericTypeThatIsSetInTheInheritingClass> ChildList
    {
        get
        {
            return _ChildList;
        }
        set
        {
            _ChildList = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any idea on how to achiv this !

Best regards, 
Fabianus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look as follows:

```
// T generic parameter must inherit EventBase<T>
public class EventBase<T>
    where T : EventBase<T>
{
    public virtual T Parent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public virtual ICustomList<T> ChildList { get; set; } = new CustomList<T>()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
    public abstract class PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical <T> 
{

    private T _Parent;
    virtual public T Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return _Parent;
        }
        set
        {
            _Parent = value;
            UpdatePropertiesInHierachy();
        }
    }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    private ICustomList<T> _ChildList = new CustomList<T>();
    virtual public ICustomList<T> ChildList
    {
        get
        {
            return _ChildList;
        }
        set
        {
            _ChildList = value;
            UpdatePropertiesInHierachy();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check mine, it uses a generic constraint.

Comment: And also I refactored your code to use auto-properties and property initializers.

Comment: Hey @MatíasFidemraizer - thank you so much ! This is just what I needed. My answer is just half the way ....

Answer (score 0):

could it be that it has to go like this ?

```
    public abstract class PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical<T> : PersistentObjectBaseWithName where T : PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical<T>
{

    private PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical<T> _Parent;
    virtual public PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical<T> Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return _Parent;
        }
        set
        {
            _Parent = value;
            UpdatePropertiesInHierachy();
        }
    }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    private ICustomList<PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical<T>> _ChildList = new CustomList<PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical<T>>();
    virtual public ICustomList<PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical<T>> ChildList
    {
        get
        {
            return _ChildList;
        }
        set
        {
            _ChildList = value;
            UpdatePropertiesInHierachy();
        }
    }


    public void AddChild(PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical<T> child)
    {
        if (ChildList.Count() != 0)
            child.OrderPosition = ChildList.Max(e => e.OrderPosition) + 1;

        ChildList.Add(child);
    }

    public void OrderChildList()
    {
        foreach (var e in ChildList)
        {
            e.OrderChildList();
        }
        ChildList.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.OrderPosition.CompareTo(s2.OrderPosition));
    }

    public int Level
    {
        get
        {
            if (Parent != null)
            {
                return Parent.Level + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }


    private double _OrderPosition;
    virtual public double OrderPosition
    {
        get
        {
            if (_OrderPosition == 0)
            {
                // We use the Id as OrderPosition to keep creation order by default
                _OrderPosition = Id;
            }
            return _OrderPosition;
        }
        set
        {
            _OrderPosition = value;
            Parent?.ChildList.Sort((s1, s2) => s1.OrderPosition.CompareTo(s2.OrderPosition));
            UpdatePropertiesInHierachy();
        }
    }

    public void UpdatePropertiesInHierachy()
    {
        PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical<T> r = GetRoot(this);
        DuringUpdatePropertiesInHierachy();
    }
```

Because otherwise I get an error here:

GetRoot(this)

telling

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'HostSystems.Models.PersistentObjectBaseWithNameHierarchical' to 'T'

Thanks for any further advice !

Regards, 
Fabianus